# Why is `datatype(?o)` empty in this query?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I was surprised to run this query

```sql
SELECT ?s, datatype(?s), ?p, datatype(?p), ?o, datatype(?o)
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

and discover that the `datatype(?o)` column is blank.
The first row of the result shows this:

```
?s           http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate  
datatype(?s) http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI    
?p           http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type    
datatype(?p) http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI    
?o           http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty
datatype(?o)
```

The [definition of the datatype function in the SPARQL 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-datatype) doesn't shed any light into why `datatype(?o)` would be empty. I don't know whether this is expected behavior or whether it's a Virtuoso quirk.

Comment: I think you've hit a relatively recently introduced bug. It would be helpful if you would raise this as an [issue on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Answer (score 0):

`datatype(?s)` evaluates to an error.

`datatype` takes a literal for an argument but `?p` and `?s` can't be literals and `?o` isn't in the data shown.

As error in a assignment (BIND, or here project expression) leaves it unbound.

With legal SPARQL syntax:

`SELECT (datatype(<http//example/>) AS ?dts ) {}`

evaluates to

```
-------
| dts |
=======
|     |
-------
```